# The integral of $\frac{\sin(x^2)}{x}\, \text{d}x$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I need to calculate the following integral;
$$\int\limits_0^{∞} \frac{\sin(x^2)}{x}\,\text{d}x$$

But, I don't really have any ideas. Maybe using a new variable or integrating by parts would work. Can I get help?

Comment: substitute $y=x^2?$

Comment: **Hint**  Let $x=\sqrt t$

Comment: Yes, thank you so much